# Why are list(), dict(), and tuple() slower than [], {}, and ()?

Tags: python

I've recently looked into using `list()`, `dict()`, `tuple()` in place of `[]`, `{}`, and `()`, respectively when needing to create an empty one of of the three. The reasoning is that it seemed more readable. I was going to ask for opinions on the style, but then I decided to test performance. I did this:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer('for x in range(5): y = []').timeit()
0.59327821802969538
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer('for x in range(5): y = list()').timeit()
1.2198944904251618
```

I tried `dict()`, `tuple()` and `list()` and the function call version of each was incredibly worse than the syntactical version (`{}` `[]`, `()`) So, I have 3 questions:

1. Why are the function calls more expensive?
2. Why is there so much difference?
3. Why the heck does it take 1.2 seconds to create 5 empty lists in my timer? I know `timeit` turns off garbage collection, but that couldn't possibly have an effect when considering I only used `range(5)`.

Comment: re: style opinion - I use [] pretty frequently. I think it's clear enough. The performance question is interesting though.

Comment: there are many things that look weird about python until you get used to them.  I would always prefer `[]` to `list()` because `list()` might actually not be `__builtins__.list`.  buyer beware.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the function call requires a variable name lookup, followed by a function invocation.  the function called then creates a list and returns it.  The list syntax literal gets the interpreter to just make a list:

```
>>> import dis
>>> foo = lambda :[]
>>> bar = lambda :list()
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

To answer #3.

[timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) actually repeats your program 1 000 000 times by default. So in fact, you are creating 5 million lists in 1.2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

```
  >>> from dis import dis

  >>> dis(lambda: list())
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 RETURN_VALUE        

  >>> dis(lambda: [])
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope lookups are required in order to find `dict`, `tuple`, and `list`, and multiple scopes need to be searched in order to find them. With the syntactic sugar the compiler can know that a specific object needs to be created and so can emit the proper bytecode to do so.

Comment: `[]` is not syntactic sugar for anything.  It is a list literal.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: It is indeed syntactic sugar. Lists can be generated by invoking `list()`, but the compiler will interpret square brackets in the appropriate context as creating a list.

Comment: the compiler does *NOT* invoke `list()` when it encounters `[]`.  see my answer.