# Why is list(xrange) slower than range()?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I was doing a couple of tests, and found that `xrange()` is MUCH faster than `range()` (as confirmed by various questions/answers as well):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(stmt = 'x = range(1000)', number = 10000)
0.38216601211680734
>>> timeit(stmt = 'x = xrange(1000)', number = 10000)
0.010537726631953959 # xrange is much faster than range
```

I got curious, so I tried another test, to see if `list(xrange(1000))` would still be faster than simply `range(1000)`:

```
>>> timeit(stmt = 'x = range(1000)', number = 10000)
0.3858838963796529
>>> timeit(stmt = 'x = list(xrange(1000))', number = 10000)
0.492734766028903 # now, xrange is slower
```

This is also true for more calls:

```
>>> timeit(stmt = 'x = range(1000)', number = 100000)
3.6457308233315757
>>> timeit(stmt = 'x = list(xrange(1000))', number = 100000)
5.722031755612818
```

So, my question is, why is `list(xrange)` significantly slower than `range` itself?

I saw [this question on the slowness of `list()`, `dict()`, and other constructor methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241716/why-are-list-dict-and-tuple-slower-than-and), so is that why `list(xrange)` is so much slower?

Using `dis.dis()`, I found that `list(xrange)` performs more computations than `range`):

```
>>> dis.dis('x = list(xrange(1000))')
          0 SETUP_LOOP      15648 (to 15651)
          3 SLICE+2        
          4 IMPORT_NAME     29545 (29545)
          7 LOAD_GLOBAL     30760 (30760)
         10 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE 28257
         13 BUILD_LIST      10341
         16 <49>           
         17 <48>           
         18 <48>           
         19 <48>           
         20 STORE_SLICE+1  
         21 STORE_SLICE+1  
>>> dis.dis('x = range(1000)')
          0 SETUP_LOOP      15648 (to 15651)
          3 SLICE+2        
          4 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE 28257
          7 BUILD_LIST      10341
         10 <49>           
         11 <48>           
         12 <48>           
         13 <48>           
         14 STORE_SLICE+1
```

Comment: What is the difference between range and xrange - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange

Comment: @ndpu I know the difference between the two. I am wondering why `list(xrange)` is slower than `range` itself.

Comment: `xrange(1000)` doesn't create a list at all. It's a generator. It's closer to assigning a constant than creation of a list, in terms of performance.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac What's your point? OP knows that, and it's not in any way related to the question.

Comment: @delnan If that was the case, why does he compare them and sound surprised about it? Saying that xrange() is MUCH [sic] faster than range() is a pointless statement, because they do entirely different things. Also, if he knew it, the answer to the question would be self-evident, because it's simply more overhead to achieve the same thing. It was not intended as a response to his actual question, which is why I didn't post it as an answer, but I thought it might help the confusion of the two terms.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac The comparison is between `list(xrange(n))` and `range(n)`, not between `xrange(n)` and `range(n)` ;-) But I see your point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course `range()` is going to be faster, when the end product you desire is a list of all numbers in a range, `range` does all of that in a single function call. As opposed to `list(xrange())` which burdens the `list(..)` constructor with the overhead of the `rangeiterator` object created to iterate over the `xrange` object, which the `list(..)` constructor must consume. Whereas `range()` constructs the list immediately, no intermediate iterator consumption... how could that be beaten? The main difference is: 1 function call vs 2 and less importantly 1 global lookup vs 2.

Answer (score 2):

`range()` will construct a list right away and return it to you. So if it has many items it is slow to build.

On the other hand, `xrange()` returns directly an iterator-like object which yields values when you ask for them. From the docs:

> **xrange(start, stop[, step])**
>   This function is very similar to range(), but returns an *xrange* object instead of a list. This is an opaque sequence type which yields the same values as the corresponding list, without actually storing them all simultaneously. The advantage of `xrange()` over `range()` is minimal (since `xrange()` still has to create the values when asked for them) **except** when a very large range is used on a memory-starved machine or when all of the range’s elements are never used (such as when the loop is usually terminated with break).

So, in your first example, `xrange()` is naturally faster, while in the second one it's slower because, while `range()` already returns a list (which won't be converted then), `list(xrange())` will have to do more work to not only produce values, but also creating a new list and storing values in.

P.S. This holds true for Python 2. In Python 3, instead, there is only `range()` which works exactly like the Python 2-`xrange()`.

Comment: @Blender: Yes added. Thanks. However the OP does not seem to have clear the base difference between `range()` and `xrange()` (just look at the first sentence) so I thought I was going to clarify it.

Comment: I knew the difference prior to asking this question.